How to Prevent Total Issuance Reduction After the Transactions in a Substrate Chain?
In my Substrate solo chain, the total issuance starts at 80,000,000,100,000,000,000,000,000. After the first transaction, it drops to 80,000,000,099,999,999,729,766,850.
I understand this could be caused by someintrisic mechanism. We want our total issuance to stay static at 80 million. Are there mechanisms or configurations in Substrate to prevent the total issuance from chainging?

This is likely caused by the pallet-transaction-payment configuration.
The transaction fee was set as OnUnbalanced = (), indicating it will be burned. However, you can change this to treasury or the block author.
For example

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/82117ad53fc68e8097183e759926b62265ffff0a/cumulus/parachains/runtimes/coretime/coretime-rococo/src/lib.rs#L266
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/82117ad53fc68e8097183e759926b62265ffff0a/cumulus/parachains/common/src/impls.rs#L63

This goes to the staking pot.

It seems there no OnUnbalanced in the Config of pallet-transaction-payment in at tag stable2409. Maybe type OnChargeTransaction = FungibleAdapter<Balances, ()>; is what needs to be changed?

Added an example.

This helps a lot. Thank you!
